# Are there any known viruses/malware that can infect Ubuntu that come from the USB?

Tags: malware, linux, virus, usb

I know that most viruses that can infect the OS from having an infected USB inserted into the PC are mostly Windows only, but is there any possibility that there is one that can affect Ubuntu as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Search for "USB Rubber Ducky" or BadUSB.

The USB device introduces itself to the computer as a keyboard and can then installs malware.